# Look up nodes that reference a given node

Tags: 7, nodes, database

I'm using the references module (not grounded to it, but it seems to work well enough) however I don't know how in a custom PHP block/etc I would be able to do a query that can look up all the nodes of a given type that reference the current node.

What sort of query would accomplish this?

For just looking up by type I've used this previously:

```
<?php
    foreach(node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => 'homepage_image')) as $node){
    //code
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you know, this is one of the problems that gave birth to relation. Nonetheless, an `EntityFieldQuery` with a `fieldCondition('name_of_the_reference_field', 'nid', $nid)` is what you want.

Comment: I'm not necessarily against using Relation if it's a better module for this sort of thing; I'm still early in development. I may give it a shot to see if it works better. Do you have an example of how to accomplish it in Relations?

Comment: I would like to thank you for fieldCondition('name_of_the_reference_field', 'nid', $nid). In my case, using user reference via entityreference. Been googling around for 2 hours and finally ended up here. As you know entityreference do not support views filtering yet. And your clue is a god send. Thanks a lot.